# What does the GetListItems query option IncludeMandatoryColumns do?

Tags: list, web-services, caml-query

I found myself working with the [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586530%28office.11%29.aspx) method fairly often. Unfortunately, I have never understood what the `IncludeMandatoryColumns` query option actually does. The documentation seems to *imply* that when set to `FALSE` it should only return columns specified in your viewFields parameter.

```
<QueryOptions>
   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
</QueryOptions>
```

Further reading:

- [Unable to get all fields of a list using GetListItems in sharepoint web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625995/unable-to-get-all-fields-of-a-list-using-getlistitems-in-sharepoint-web-services)
- [Sharepoint Lists.asmx: remove “ows_MetaInfo” field from GetListItems method response xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397864/sharepoint-lists-asmx-remove-ows-metainfo-field-from-getlistitems-method-respo)
- [Why does  criteria get ignored by the SharePoint List Service's GetListItems Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248000/why-does-viewfields-criteria-get-ignored-by-the-sharepoint-list-services-getli)
- [Getting back spurious fields to GetListItems query, even with IncludeMandatoryColumns set FALSE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b5b58ad7-e379-4f50-a07b-76b31dda4799/)
- [Bug in SharePoint’s Lists Web Service with GetListItems?](http://sympmarc.com/2010/05/08/bug-in-sharepoints-lists-web-service-with-getlistitems/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of this value, you will always get a couple of core fields returned with your dataset that are not in your ViewFields. IncludeMandatoryField expands it to include things like fields flagged as required, dependent fields for calculated and computed columns, and some additional metadata fields that are normally hidden from the UI.

Comment: Ok, so no matter what the value some "core fields" will always be returned. What determines if a field is a "core field"?

Comment: It coded somewhere in the depths... you can't change it. In the past when writing some custom web services I filtered it out of the result returned to the client manually.

Comment: @KitMenke can it be defined in core content-type? I found only 2 fields in Item content-type, but when you create a new View from SP admin page, there is 15 available. Where did they get it?

Comment: Content types are templates for content and have to be associated with a list or library to use. Those extra fields such as created by and modified by are not on the content types, they system fields that are part of lists and libraries. No, you can't add those columns to the core content type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug. It does however bring in the fields you specify in ViewFields first. So you could potentially do a workaround that only returns the first X columns, where X is the number of ViewFields specified.