# ViewFields: additional fields

Tags: web-services

I use SP web-services to fetch list items (rows). 
I want to be able to load all available fields for the list and pick some of them to be returned for each list item.
So I use Lists.asmx#GetList to fetch all Fields, pick StaticName from it, and send it to Lists.asmx#GetListItems in <ViewFields>.
Why some fields displayed in GetList doesn't return by GetListItems? (For example 'ContentTypeID' returns well, but '_HasCopyDestination' doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had so many issues with what fields do or don't get returned from that method I pretty much just accept it will be broken. Some more info here [What does the GetListItems query option IncludeMandatoryColumns do?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/what-does-the-getlistitems-query-option-includemandatorycolumns-do)

Some examples from a Document library:

`<Field ID="{4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Type="Text" Name="Created_x0020_By" DisplayName="Document Created By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created_x0020_By" FromBaseType="TRUE" ColName="nvarchar2"/>`

Title field: `<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" DisplayName="Title" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" ColName="nvarchar7"/>`

You can try filtering out some of the fields that use `FromBaseType="TRUE"` or `Hidden="TRUE"` but then again.. maybe you want Created By?

A blacklist would probably work but make sure it is configurable so you can add new ones you find later. :)

Comment: Thanks again. It looks like FromBaseType="TRUE" will opt out all mandatory fields like Modified, Created, etc. Also, you can use static name "Author", instead "Created_x0020_By" to see who created the item. I will filter by hidden==true.