# Full schema for View

Tags: column, view, schema

How would I fetch all **Fields** for specified *View* via web-service?

P.S. When I call GetView on Views.asmx, only visible **Fields** appear.

[EDIT]

I fetch schema for my list (with Lists.asmx#GetList), which contains 55 Fields. I pick one of them and request list items with it (to add new column to listitem/row). The problem is not all fields are displayed, for example "Author" can be added to listitem/row as a column, but "_ModerationComments" or "_HasCopyDestinations" doesn't. 
I'm trying to display all available columns for specified list and let user pick columns that he want's to be displayed in a grid of list items.

Comment: I don't understand... if a field is not in the view, it will be invisible, but if a field is in the view, it will be visible.

Comment: @SteveB I've edited the question.

Comment: In fact, you want to get the list schema instead of the view schema, don't you ? If yes, maybe you can use [List web service's GetList method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let user pick from all available fields, the GetList needs to be called on Lists.asmx (which returns all fields for specified list).
It looks like the same thing was done in the page of SP admin web-application, for editing the view, but all fields (55 for example) was filtered by hidden==false, so it's about 15 items remained.
Also, see [ViewFields question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54009/viewfields-additional-fields) for more details.